# When citing a thesis, do I list supervisors as coauthors?

Tags: citations

I am citing someone's bachelors thesis, and someone else's PhD thesis. Do I include the supervisors for each of these works as a coauthor of the thesis?

Comment: What does the theses your are writing say - ie- who do they list as an author? What does the citation style you are writing to say (if anything) about citing theses?

Comment: @nabla The title page lists a single author (the student), then explicit states the name of the supervisor, e.g. *"Superivsor: Prof ABC"*. I am not required to use and therefore not using any formal citation style—I'm using whatever BibLaTeX's authoryear style gives me. I don't believe this style says anything about citing theses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When citing, you should include the document's author(s). For a thesis, that'll be a single author. You needn't name any other contributors, e.g., any supervisors.

Comment: _that'll be a single author_ At least, I cannot think of an exception...

Comment: In some countries (for example, Sweden), bachelor's and master's theses can be developed by multiple authors. I think there even exist historical cases of multi-author PhD theses in the former German Democratic Republic.

Comment: Could we compare citing the supervisors of a thesis to citing people in the acknowledgements of a paper? Even though the supervisor contributed, the thesis was solely written by a single author. Much the same, as people who I publicly thank in the acknowledgements may have contributed much, the paper was written by me and my co-authors.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I preempted your comment ;-)

Comment: @DohnJoe A better comparison would perhaps be citing a poctdoc's supervisor